# C# how to show dialog box like IE in my web browser control

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a problem with access my physical location.
If I use Internet Explorer on my laptop, it gives me the dialog in the image below:
[image]

But, in my web browser control, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: You might want to clear browsing history - Ctrl + Shift + Delete. Or, try InPrivate browsing - Ctrl + Shift + P.

Comment: @Win thank's for your advice. but the problem is my web browser control on winforms doesn't show dialog box like IE. any advice ?